# Morphism between rings of Laurent polynomials.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $I_n = \text{Set}([1,n],\mathbb{Z})$. We define a ring homomorphism $f_{nn-1}:\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n] \to \mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}]$ by
\begin{equation}
x_i \mapsto \begin{cases} x_i, & i \leq n-1, \\ 
                          0, & i=n
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
extended algebraically. Suppose we now want to define "the same" ring homomorphism  between rings
$\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm1},\dots,x_n^{\pm1}]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm1},\dots,x_{n-1}^{\pm1}]$ of Laurent polynomials. Clearly, we can no longer send $x_n$ to $0$. Instead, we define $g_{nn-1}:\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm1},\dots,x_n^{\pm1}] \to \mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm1},\dots,x_{n-1}^{\pm1}]$ as:
\begin{equation}
g_{nn-1}\bigg(\displaystyle\sum_{\alpha \in I_n}c_{\alpha}x^{\alpha}\bigg)=\displaystyle\sum_{\beta \in I_{n-1}}d_{\beta}x^{\beta},
\end{equation}
with $d_{\beta}=c_{\alpha(\beta)},$ where \begin{equation}
I_n  \ni \alpha(\beta)_i=\begin{cases} \beta_i, &i \leq n-1, \\
                                       0, i=n.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Esentially, the coefficients of monomials involving non-zero powers of $x_n$ are ignored. Is this ok or am I doing something which is not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $x_n\in\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_n^{\pm 1}]$. This has $c_\alpha=0$ for all $\alpha\neq(0,\dots,0,1)$, and $c_{(0,\dots,0,1)}=1$. Since $(0,\dots,0,1)\neq\alpha(\beta)$ for any $\beta\in I_{n-1}$, this means that $g_{nn-1}(x_n)=0$. This means that $g_{nn-1}$ cannot be a ring homomorphism, since $x_n$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_n^{\pm 1}]$ and so its image under any ring homomorphism must be a unit in $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_{n-1}^{\pm 1}]$.

---

Here is any easy way to define maps out of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_n^{\pm 1}]$. In my view, it is easier to think about this ring as the quotient ring $$R:=\frac{\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_n]}{(x_1y_1-1,\dots,x_ny_n-1)}.$$ By the [universal property of quotient rings](http://ptwiddle.github.io/MAS439-Commutative-Algebra/slides/Lecture7.pdf), defining a ring homomorphism from $R$ to another ring $S$ is the same as defining a ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}[\bar{x},\bar{y}]\rightarrow S$ such that $(x_i y_i-1)_{i\leqslant n}\subseteq\ker{f}$.

Now, sending the generators of an ideal to $0$ will be enough to send the whole ideal to $0$, so the condition $(x_i y_i-1)_{i\leqslant n}\subseteq\ker{f}$ is really the same as requiring $$0=f(x_iy_i-1)=f(x_i)f(y_i)-1$$ for each $i$. In other, $f$ sends the ideal $(x_i y_i-1)_{i\leqslant n}$ to $0$ if and only if $f(x_i)$ is the multiplicative inverse of $f(y_i)$ for each $i$. Thus, any ring morphism $f:\mathbb{Q}[\bar{x},\bar{y}]\rightarrow S$ such that each $f(x_i)$ is a unit with $f(y_i)$ as its inverse can be turned into a ring morphism $R\rightarrow S$.

If you're only interested in defining maps to *commutative* rings $S$, then we can simplify even further. Indeed, by the [universal property of polynomial rings](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Polynomial_Ring), defining a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}[\bar{x},\bar{y}]$ to a commutative ring $S$ is the same as defining a ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $S$ and then choosing *any* elements $s_1,\dots,s_n\in S$ and $t_1,\dots,t_n\in S$ to send the $x_i$ and the $y_i$ to. (We take $x_i\mapsto s_i$ and $t_i\mapsto t_i$.)

So, putting these two facts together, here is a recipe for defining maps $f:R\rightarrow S$, where $S$ is commutative. First, define a map $g:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow S$. Then choose *any* units $s_1,\dots,s_n\in S^\times$. Then we can glue these two ingredients together to get a map $f:R\rightarrow S$ such that $f(q)=g(q)$ for any $q\in\mathbb{Q}$, $f(x_i)=s_i$ for each $i$, and $f(y_i)=s_i^{-1}$ for each $i$.

In your notation for the Laurent ring, defining a map $f:\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_n^{\pm 1}]\rightarrow S$ where $S$ is commutative is then the same as defining a map $g:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow S$ and choosing any units $s_1,\dots,s_n\in S^\times$ to map each $x_i$ to. Once you have chosen the image of $x_i$ to be $s_i$, that forces the image of $x_i^{-1}$ to be $s_i^{-1}$.

So, for example, when $S$ is another Laurent ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_{n-1}^{\pm 1}]$, the natural thing to do is to define $g:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow S$ by $g(q)=q$, and let $s_i=x_i$ for each $i<n$. Since each $x_i$, is invertible in $S$ for $i<n$, we have each of these $s_i\in S^\times$, as needed. Let's assume you're only interested in maps that act this way, ie that act like the identity on the subring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_{n-1}^{\pm 1}]$ of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_{n}^{\pm 1}]$

We still need to choose $s_n$, which is to be the image of $x_n$. By our discussion above, we can choose $s_n$ to be *any* unit of $S$; for instance, we can let $x_n$ map to $x_i$, for any $i<n$, or let $x_n$ map to any non-zero element of $\mathbb{Q}$. More generally, note that any monomial $x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_{n-1}^{\alpha_{n-1}}\in S$, with $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, is a unit, and has inverse given by $x_1^{-\alpha_1}\dots x_{n-1}^{-\alpha_{n-1}}\in S$. Thus we can let $x_n$ map to $x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_{n-1}^{\alpha_{n-1}}\in S$ if we wish.

In fact, every unit of $S$ is of the form $\lambda x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_{n-1}^{\alpha_{n-1}}$ where $\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ and each $\alpha_i\in\mathbb{Z}$, so for every such element of $S$ there is a ring homomorphism from $R$ to $S$ that sends $x_n$ to $\lambda x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_{n-1}^{\alpha_{n-1}}$. Conversely, no ring homomorphism from $R$ to $S$ can send $x_n$ to a non-unit, so these are all of the possible images for $x_n$, and thus this gives a complete characterization of the maps you are interested in. Concretely, once we've chosen $s_n\in S^\times$, the induced map will act by replacing every instance of $x_n$ in a polynomial of $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_{n}^{\pm 1}]$ by $s_n$.

If you enjoy these constructions, I recommend looking into [localization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localization_(commutative_algebra)), which is a big generalization of some of the ideas above and serves as a very powerful/important tool in commutative algebra. In this language, the Laurent polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1^{\pm 1},\dots,x_n^{\pm 1}]$ is the *localization* of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ at the multiplicative set generated by $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$.

Comment: Ohh, of course, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @amator2357 happy it helped! :)

Comment: I did indeed! Is there a way of "sending  $x_n$ to $0$" without breaking things in this Laurent polynomial setup?

Comment: @amator2357 so, in general, there is only one ring in which $0$ is a unit, and that is the "zero ring" $R=\{0\}$; then the zero map from the Laurent series ring to $R$ sends $x_n$ to $0$. for any other ring $S$ however, $0$ will not be a unit in $S$, so there is no way to send the unit $x_n$ in the Laurent series ring to the non-unit $0$ in $S$. if you'd like I'll write up a few paragraphs on a sort of recipe for defining ring homomorphisms out of a Laurent series ring! there is actually quite a nice characterization of these maps available

Comment: I see. If you have time (and whenever you have it) to write it then I'd be very interested to read it!

Comment: @amator2357 done! let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate this! I will go through it carefully now.